# Servlet.init() for servlet spring-dispatcher threw exception(XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException)

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets, xml-configuration

Okay so i am working on spring mvc for the first time and i dont know how to resolve this error. I am trying out a simple mvc program

here is my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>FirstSpringMVCProject</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

here is my spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <beans id="HandlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>
    <beans name="/welcome.html" class="com.rohit.hellocontroller.HelloController"/>

    <beans id="viewResolver" class ="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

        <property name="prefix">            
             <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>

        <property name="suffix">            
             <value>.jsp </value>           
        </property>

    </beans>
</beans>
```

following is my hello controller.java

```
package com.rohit.hellocontroller;

import javax.servlet.http.*;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;

public class HelloController  extends AbstractController {


    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest arg0,
            HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception {

        ModelAndView modelview= new ModelAndView("HelloPage");
        modelview.addObject("welcomeMessage","Hi there user this is my own written message");

        return modelview;
    }

}
```

and the last one is hellopage.jsp

```
<html>

    <body>

    <h1 style="color:blue">My first spring mvc progrram</h1>

    <h2>${welcomeMessage}</h2></body>
</html>
```

following is the stacktrace for error

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet spring-dispatcher threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


root cause 

org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 4 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 71; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:395)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:443)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:340)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:307)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


root cause 

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 71; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:395)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:443)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:340)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:307)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

sorry if there are indentation errors this is my first question.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `bean` tag instead of `beans` tag in your spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml file.

```
  <bean id="HandlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>

  <bean name="/welcome.html" class="com.rohit.hellocontroller.HelloController"/>

  <bean id="viewResolver" class ="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
```

Comment: it worked thanks but now there is error regarding "requested resource not available" probably tomcat server..... can it be coz of improper installation??

Comment: Can you post this as separate question with details?

Comment: sure. thats doable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44514882/the-requested-resource-is-not-available-on-running-spring-mvc-program-on-eclipse

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44514882/the-requested-resource-is-not-available-on-running-spring-mvc-program-on-eclipse