# The requested resource is not available.on running spring mvc program on eclipse with tomcat

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-mvc, tomcat

I was trying to run the basic spring mvc program but when i run i get the above mentioned error

```
HTTP Status 404 - 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message 

description The requested resource is not available.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/7.0.35
```

console log is

```
Jun 13, 2017 12:50:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd;C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.3.0\bin;C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\;C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm;D:\Softwares\eclipse\eclipse;
Jun 13, 2017 12:50:01 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:FirstSpringMVCProject' did not find a matching property.
Jun 13, 2017 12:50:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9999"]
Jun 13, 2017 12:50:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 13, 2017 12:50:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1458 ms
Jun 13, 2017 12:50:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jun 13, 2017 12:50:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.35
Jun 13, 2017 12:50:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9999"]
Jun 13, 2017 12:50:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 13, 2017 12:50:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 6638 ms
```

web.xml file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>FirstSpringMVCProject</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  </web-app>
```

content from spring-dispatcher.xml is as followss

```
<bean xmlns="https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

        <bean id="HandlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>
        <bean name="/welcome.html" class="com.rohit.hellocontroller.HelloController"/>

        <bean id="viewResolver" class ="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

        <property name="prefix">

        <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>

        <property name="suffix">

        <value>.jsp </value>

        </property>

        </bean>




        </bean>
```

here is my hellocontroller class file

```
package com.rohit.hellocontroller;
 import javax.servlet.http.*;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;
public class HelloController  extends AbstractController{


    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest arg0,
            HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception {

        ModelAndView modelview= new ModelAndView("HelloPage");
        modelview.addObject("welcomeMessage","Hi there user this is my own written message");

        return modelview;
    }

}
```

here is my class path stack

[image]
i dont think there is a problem with the running of tomcat server because console log shows it as started.Still cant figure out why the resource can't be located..... Any help would be great

console log on hitting url

```
Jun 14, 2017 10:19:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd;C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.3.0\bin;C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\;C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm;D:\Softwares\eclipse\eclipse;
Jun 14, 2017 10:19:09 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:FirstSpringMVCProject' did not find a matching property.
Jun 14, 2017 10:19:09 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9999"]
Jun 14, 2017 10:19:09 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 14, 2017 10:19:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1130 ms
Jun 14, 2017 10:19:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jun 14, 2017 10:19:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.35
Jun 14, 2017 10:19:16 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9999"]
Jun 14, 2017 10:19:16 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 14, 2017 10:19:16 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 6669 ms
Jun 14, 2017 10:19:52 AM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpMessage processHeader
SEVERE: Invalid message received with signature 18245
Jun 14, 2017 10:19:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
WARNING: StandardServer.await: Invalid command 'GET / HTTP/1.1' received
Jun 14, 2017 10:20:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
WARNING: StandardServer.await: read: 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:766)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:712)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)

Jun 14, 2017 10:20:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
WARNING: StandardServer.await: Invalid command '' received
Jun 14, 2017 10:20:07 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
WARNING: StandardServer.await: Invalid command 'GET / HTTP/1.1' received
Jun 14, 2017 10:20:11 AM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpMessage processHeader
SEVERE: Invalid message received with signature 18245
Jun 14, 2017 10:20:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
WARNING: StandardServer.await: read: 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:766)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:712)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)

Jun 14, 2017 10:20:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
WARNING: StandardServer.await: Invalid command '' received
```

Comment: Please update your project folder structure and helloController class  here ..

Answer (score 0):

The reasons for this may be-

1. Make sure the path specified in spring-dispatcher.xml file for your views is correct (/WEB-INF/)
2. While making the ModelAndView object in the HelloController, you are specifying the correct file name.

Comment: Are you using this url for getting the response - > localhost:8080/FirstSpringMVCProject/welcome.html

Comment: At your controller method , pass the bean defined in the spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml file @RequestMapping("/welcome.html")

Comment: here is console log

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following line from your `spring-dispatcher.xml`

```
<bean name="/welcome.html" class="com.rohit.hellocontroller.HelloController"/>
```

Update  with the following in your `HelloController`:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController{
      @RequestMapping("/")
      public ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest arg0,
                    HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception {
               return new ModelAndView("HelloPage","welcomeMessage","Hi there user this is my own written message");

            }
    }
```

Comment: the modelview.setview(""HelloPage""); gives error as "setView is a type of view and not applicable to String"  so i commented that line but still no effect

Comment: Try with updated controller code and hit **localhost:8080/FirstSpringMVCProject/**

Comment: tried the above thing too but it doesnt work although i checked in eclipse port for tomcat was 8005, i tried with that too but that doesnt take me to the homepage for tomcat

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: code runs without any problem, the resource not found error persists . on hitting the url, page not found

Comment: Please come to this chat room  https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146596/spring-application-resource-not-found

Comment: it says i must have 20 reputation to join the chat room

Comment: though i tried something and the error message changed

Comment: HTTP Status 404 - /FirstSpringMVCProject/WEB-INF/classes/com/rohit/hellocontroller/HelloController.java

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message /FirstSpringMVCProject/WEB-INF/classes/com/rohit/hellocontroller/HelloController.java

description The requested resource is not available.